# javaFX: radio buttons inside listview selectionmodel

Tags: java, javafx

I need `RadioButtons` inside `ListView` so i find this answer:

[javaFX:listview with Radio Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027953/javafxlistview-with-radio-button)

but the problem is that selected cell in `ListView` and selected `RadioButton` are not bind. If a click on cell in list i want automatically to select the corresponding `RadioButton`.

So my question is how can i bind this two?

**UPDATE:**
So the only way i managed to do it is similar to @Sedrick Jefferson answer but without adding `StackPane` in front of `RadioButton`. 
I add list of `RadioButtons` namesRadioButtons to `ToggleGroup` and add listener to `selectedToggleProperty`: when new `RadioButton` is selected i select corresponding row in `ListView`

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RadioButtonListView extends Application
{

    public static final ObservableList<RadioButton> namesRadioButtons
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("List View Sample");

        final ListView<RadioButton> listView = new ListView();
        listView.setPrefSize(200, 250);
        listView.setEditable(true);

        String[] names =
        {
            "Adam", "Alex", "Alfred", "Albert",
            "Brenda", "Connie", "Derek", "Donny",
            "Lynne", "Myrtle", "Rose", "Rudolph",
            "Tony", "Trudy", "Williams", "Zach"
        };

        for (String name : names)
        {
            namesRadioButtons.add(new RadioButton(name));
        }
        group.getToggles().addAll(namesRadioButtons);
        listView.setItems(namesRadioButtons);
        group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((obs, oldSel, newSel) -> {
            listView.getSelectionModel().select((RadioButton) newSel);
            listView.getFocusModel().focus(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        });
        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new RadioListCell());
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSel, newSel) ->
        {
            if (newSel != null)
            {
                RadioButton tempRadioButton = (RadioButton) newSel;
                tempRadioButton.setSelected(true);
            }
            if (oldSel != null)
            {
                RadioButton tempRadioButton = (RadioButton) oldSel;
                tempRadioButton.setSelected(false);
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(listView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class RadioListCell extends ListCell<RadioButton>
    {

        @Override
        public void updateItem(RadioButton obj, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(obj, empty);
            if (empty)
            {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            }
            else
            {
                setGraphic(obj);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Question: Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: as I already said: it's completely wrong to use controls as data items - so what you are doing is wrong as well. Instead, use a custom cell, that has a radiobutton (just as in the QA you cited), configure it with text/selected state as needed. To keep the list's selection state in synch with the button state, listen to the radio's selected _in the cell_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat: adding controls as data items is *not* a solution!

Instead, use a custom cell that has-a control as needed and configure with the state of the item/list/selection, just as in the [QA cited by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027953/javafxlistview-with-radio-button). The only part missing is the back-sync (from the radio state to the list selection): to achieve that, install a listener in the cell.

Something like (modified example):

```
public class RadioButtonListView extends Application {

    public static final ObservableList names =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("List View Sample");

        final ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.setPrefSize(200, 250);
        listView.setEditable(true);

        names.addAll(
                "Adam", "Alex", "Alfred", "Albert",
                "Brenda", "Connie", "Derek", "Donny",
                "Lynne", "Myrtle", "Rose", "Rudolph",
                "Tony", "Trudy", "Williams", "Zach"
        );

        listView.setItems(names);
        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new RadioListCell());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(listView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class RadioListCell extends ListCell<String> {

        RadioButton radioButton;
        ChangeListener<Boolean> radioListener = (src, ov, nv) -> radioChanged(nv);
        WeakChangeListener<Boolean> weakRadioListener = new WeakChangeListener(radioListener);

        public RadioListCell() {
            radioButton = new RadioButton();
            radioButton.selectedProperty().addListener(weakRadioListener);
            radioButton.setFocusTraversable(false);
            // let it span the complete width of the list
            // needed in fx8 to update selection state
            radioButton.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        protected void radioChanged(boolean selected) {
            if (selected && getListView() != null && !isEmpty() && getIndex() >= 0) {
                getListView().getSelectionModel().select(getIndex());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String obj, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(obj, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
                radioButton.setToggleGroup(null);
            } else {
                radioButton.setText(obj);
                radioButton.setToggleGroup(group);
                radioButton.setSelected(isSelected());
                setGraphic(radioButton);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update:

The example is working fine in fx9 but has issues in fx8:

- when clicking outside of the radiobutton (somewhere in the trailing whitespace of a row) the radio selected is not always updated. This can be fixed by forcing the radio to stretch to the full width of the list.
- the selected state of the radio is not always updated when the listView's selection changed. This can be handled by installing a listener to the cell's selected property and update the radio in that listener.
- the selected state of the radio is not reliably updated when the cell is re-used. This needs further digging ...

Comment: Yeah but this works only if you click on radiobutton, if you click on row of list (where is not radiobutton) it wont select corresponding radiobutton. Thank you anyway.

Comment: hmm ... can't reproduce your problem: the item is selected after cklicking anywhere in the row

Comment: @krupiceva you did try this modified (compared to the older QA) example, didn't you? worksforme for both fx8 and fx9

Comment: yes, and in fx8. Here how it looks when i run it: https://imgur.com/oggsMq7

Comment: Can you color the radio buttons' background and post an image? For me it looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/O0MwW), so only the red area is registered for clicks.

Comment: @krupiceva See if adding the line `radioButton.maxWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());` to the constructor helps. It's not full coverage, but [close](https://imgur.com/a/Aa7pM). Can be made better if that's what you really want.

Comment: @krupiceva thanks for the video! you are right, it's working in fx9 but not in fx8. Increasing the width as suggested by user18xx should help, though. will have to try, soon